# meteor d3 import data

Tags: d3.js, meteor

I'm having difficulties in importing data from MongoDB into the D3 heatmap function. An example can be found here: http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084
The data looks like this:
[Object { _id="DoaB3wnW7CCzxqzug", weekday=1, hour=1, value=12}, Object { _id="RnwxHbRPGdWHBaAYu", weekday=1, hour=2, value=4}]

My code looks like this:

```
Template.weeklyUsageHeatmap.rendered = function() {

    var margin = { top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 100, left: 20 },
          width = 720 - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = 340 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
          gridSize = Math.floor(width / 24),
          legendElementWidth = gridSize*2,
          buckets = 9,

            colors = ["#ffffe5","#fff7bc","#fee391","#fec44f","#fe9929","#ec7014","#cc4c02","#993404","#662506"]
          days = ["Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"],
          times = ["1a", "2a", "3a", "4a", "5a", "6a", "7a", "8a", "9a", "10a", "11a", "12a", "1p", "2p", "3p", "4p", "5p", "6p", "7p", "8p", "9p", "10p", "11p", "12p"];

    var data = WeeklyUsage.find().fetch();

    d3.json(data,
        function(d) {
            return {
                day: +d.weekday, 
                hour: +d.hour,
                value: +d.value
            };
        },
        function(error, data) {
            var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
                .domain([0, buckets - 1, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.value; })])
                .range(colors);

            var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            var dayLabels = svg.selectAll(".dayLabel")
                .data(days)
                .enter().append("text")
                .text(function (d) { return d; })
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("y", function (d, i) { return i * gridSize; })
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + gridSize / 1.5 + ")")
                .attr("class", function (d, i) { return ((i >= 0 && i <= 4) ? "dayLabel mono axis axis-workweek" : "dayLabel mono axis"); });

            var timeLabels = svg.selectAll(".timeLabel")
                .data(times)
                .enter().append("text")
                .text(function(d) { return d; })
                .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * gridSize; })
                .attr("y", 0)
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + gridSize / 2 + ", -6)")
                .attr("class", function(d, i) { return ((i >= 7 && i <= 16) ? "timeLabel mono axis axis-worktime" : "timeLabel mono axis"); });

            var heatMap = svg.selectAll(".hour")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.hour - 1) * gridSize; })
                .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.weekday - 1) * gridSize; })
                .attr("rx", 4)
                .attr("ry", 4)
                .attr("class", "hour bordered")
                .attr("width", gridSize)
                .attr("height", gridSize)
                .style("fill", colors[0]);

            heatMap.transition().duration(1000)
                .style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.value); });

            heatMap.append("title").text(function(d) { return d.value; });

            var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
                .data([0].concat(colorScale.quantiles()), function(d) { return d; })
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "legend");

            legend.append("rect")
                .attr("x", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * i; })
                .attr("y", height)
                .attr("width", legendElementWidth)
                .attr("height", gridSize / 2)
                .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

            legend.append("text")
                .attr("class", "mono")
                .text(function(d) { return "≥ " + Math.round(d); })
                .attr("x", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * i; })
                .attr("y", height + gridSize);
      });

};
```

The error I got was: d is NULL.

Comment: Did you check if the import of your data failed ? How do you access the data ? I would console.log(data) right after the function(error, data) to see what you obtained.

Comment: I did check the import. Just under var data = WeeklyUsage.find().fetch(); I wrote a console.log(data). The result was a list of [object Object] but a log on data._id resulted in "undefined".

Comment: could you run it in Chrome, set a breakpoint at your console.log and do write in the chrome console: console.table(data). Then post the result and we will probably see what goes wrong..

Comment: This is what I received in Chrome:
 showmethedata: undefined
admin.js?3bf828952d69f09f80c5e8236f3d0c381faa9e5b:53 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'weekday' of nulladmin.js?3bf828952d69f09f80c5e8236f3d0c381faa9e5b:53 (anonymous function)d3.js:2007 typed3.js:504 eventd3.js:1942 respond

Comment: Just beneath var data = WeeklyUsage.find().fetch(), I added the line: console.log('showmethedata: ' + data._weekday);

Comment: After adding the line console.table(data), I received: ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: In a small test I did, I did a call to WeeklyUsage.find() and made a template with a {{#each}} loop to iterate over the data of weekly_usage. This worked fine. So it looks like I must do something wrong at retrieving the data in the d3.json function.

Comment: From what you describe, I come to the following conclusion:

Comment: From what you describe, I come to the following conclusion: Your log "showmethedata" is saying: data is undefinded. This is BEFORE you call the d3.json() function. The d3.json expects the the first argument to be a json file which you refer to by path or by a json array (http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp). The line WeeklyUsage.find().fetch(); clearly does not return this array. You have to look what the fetch() function really returns (probably nothing), but this is not a d3.js topic, I don't know anything about meteor :( it is really about meteor skills that you end up with json.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. with this issue. Indeed, this must be a Meteor issue but I can't see how to retrieve the data in my d3.json function. The console.log gives me back a list of [object Object] objects. This means it is getting its json but not yet readable in the function.

Comment: Well sorry, I was not much help. But good luck with finding the cause / right transfornation !

Comment: Never mind. I will get there. Thanks for your time and effort.Greet, Tjeerd

Comment: hi, i too am facing the same issue how did you exactly fix this, help will be appreciated